# What algorithm used to find the nth sorted subarray of an unordered array?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I had this question recently in an interview and I failed, and now search for the answer.

1. Let's say I have a big array of n integers, all differents.
2. If this array was ordered, I could subdivide it in x smaller
   arrays, all of size y, except maybe the last one, which could be less.
   I could then extract the nth subarray and return it, already sorted.

Example : Array 4 2 5 1 6 3. If y=2 and I want the 2nd array, it would be 3 4.

Now what I did is simply sort the array and return the nth subarray, which takes `O(n log n`). But it was said to me that there exists a way to do it in `O(n + y log y)`. I searched on internet and didn't find anything. Ideas ?

Comment: Is the array starting from 1 in increasing order (just that it is shuffled) (e.g. 3,1,2,4)? Or is it random numbers which jumps? (e.g. 1,12,3,5)

Comment: From what I undestood, it is random numbers, the only prerequisite is that they are all different.

Comment: Think about how quicksort works and then think how you would use it to make sure that say the array elements 101 to 150 are sorted. Hint: That means you don't need to sort say elements 1 to 100 when quicksort would do so.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The algorithm you are looking for is [*Selection Algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), which lets you find [k-th order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) in linear time. The algorithm is quite complex, but the standard C++ library conveniently provides [an implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) of it.

The algorithm for finding k-th sorted interval that the interviewers had in mind went like this:

- Find `b=(k-1)*y`-th order statistics in O(N)
- Find `e=k*y`-th order statistics in O(N)
- There will be `y` numbers between `b` and `e`. Store them in a separate array of size `y`. This operation takes O(N)
- Sort the array of size `y` for O(y * log<sub>2</sub>y) cost.

The overall cost is O(N+N+N+y * log<sub>2</sub>y), i.e. O(N+y * log<sub>2</sub>y)

Answer (score 5):

You can combine [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) and [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for this:

```
std::vector<int> vec = muchData();
// Fix those bound iterators as needed
auto lower = vec.begin() + k*y;
auto upper = lower + y;

// put right element at lower and partition vector by it
std::nth_element(vec.begin(), lower, vec.end());
// Same for upper, but don't mess up lower
std::nth_element(lower + 1, upper - 1, vec.end());
// Now sort the subarray
std::sort(lower, upper);
```

`[lower, upper)` is now the k-th sorted subarray of length y, with the desired complexity on average.

To be checked for special cases like `y = 1` before real world use, but this is the general idea.